# Rendering text into the world in box2d

Tags: c++, box2d

I am working on Box2D in C++. I have the world created. Is there some sort of shape, or inbuilt method, which can be used to write text into the world, and at it, maybe as a fixture? Maybe this is easy, but I haven't been able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Box2D provides only two basic shapes out of the box that you may probably already know: `Polygons` and `Circles`. If you need more advanced shapes, you should go for tools like `box2d editor`